Design and calculations of wet cyclone scrubber
I'm Maaz, I want to design a wet cyclone scrubber for powder recovery and air dehumidification, and I want calculations for it, so can anybody provide me the calculations.

you can't dehumidify with a wet scrubber.  No one designs these, you buy them from the people who do.
